How To Handle Asynchronous Multiple Faculty Job Offers
I've seen a few threads about handling simultaneous offers
How do people get simultaneous offers?
How to negotiate multiple tenure-track offers
But what about potential job offers that may materialize at different times within a span of month and half?
My situation is I interviewed at one university (a non-Tiered university in the USA) yet has some recogntion in their department (locally or statewide). They plan to offer a letter relatively soon within a few weeks. After said few weeks, a Tiered university will invite me to their job interview, and depending on the outcome of the interview, may present a job offer letter later. So in this situation, two job offers but at different times. N.B. I am in a "Right to Work" state in the USA.
Would it be alright to take the first job offer and wait and see what the second job offer might be? And if I do like the second job offer, presumbly I can rescind my acceptance of the first offer?

If this comes to pass, you'd be dealing with What is the recommended option for a faculty applicant after accepting an offer and getting another better offer? or Can I back out a tenure track faculty offer?.

if your user profile is your real name, you may want to change your name here.

First of all, congrats on the offer. It's hard to get a permanent position so count yourself lucky!

But what about potential job offers that may materialize at different times within a span of month and half?

This situation is extremely common. The standard advice is: when you get your offer from university A, you can write to university B to explain that you have an offer and must respond by a specific deadline. They can then give you an indication of whether or not they were strongly considering your application or if they can speed up the process. You can also ask university A to give you a longer clock, but there is no guarantee that they will. Please remember that university A needs to hire someone or their courses will be understaffed in the fall semester. The longer you sit on the offer, the more chance their other top choices will accept jobs elsewhere and be off the market.

My situation is I interviewed at one university (a non-Tiered university in the USA) yet has some recogntion in their department (locally or statewide).

The status/level of the university is irrelevant to the ethics here. You applied to the job and your decisions now will affect whether or not their search succeeds or fails. Even if they are "non-tiered" that does not excuse behaving unethically towards them.

They plan to offer a letter relatively soon within a few weeks. After said few weeks, a Tiered university will invite me to their job interview, and depending on the outcome of the interview, may present a job offer letter later. So in this situation, two job offers but at different times.

Ok, so actually you do NOT have a firm offer from University A. You have a verbal commitment that they plan to make you an offer. Until they do so, you are free (and wise) to keep applying to other jobs and interviewing. However, once they actually make you an offer and you actually sign it, then backing out would be unethical because it would leave them in the lurch, looking at a potentially failed search and not being able to staff their courses for the fall.

N.B. I am in a "Right to Work" state in the USA.

Actually, this is irrelevant to the ethics of the situation or to the etiquette (as your question is tagged). There are plenty of activities that are legal but unethical and which could hurt your career. Generally speaking, accepting an academic job then backing out to take another job, is the kind of thing that can harm your professional reputation, for the reasons I explained above. Long-term, professional reputation matters a lot.

Would it be alright to take the first job offer and wait and see what the second job offer might be? And if I do like the second job offer, presumbly I can rescind my acceptance of the first offer?

I strongly recommend against this behavior. In an academic setting, rescinding your acceptance is unethical for the reasons I listed above (where by acceptance I mean you signed a contract). Once you sign a contract with university A, you should back out of your other searches and tell university B you are no longer on the job market. This way you don't waste their time and resources bringing you for an on-campus interview. This is why it's important to alert B when you get the offer from A, so that they have a chance to make you an offer before you accept A's. However, if it does happen that B makes you an offer after you've already accepted A, one thing you can do is ask B if you can start one year late. That way, you could go to A for a year (thereby not leaving them in the lurch without someone to teach in the fall) and shift to B after that first year. Once B agrees to let you start a year late, it would be appropriate to tell A, and then they can decide if they want to free you from the contract you signed and go back to their applicant pool right now, or just run a fresh search next year. Either way, they need to know as soon as possible, so they are not left without sufficient staffing the year after you leave.
I know it's not an ideal process and it's very annoying to deal with this situation of not having all offers at the same time. But that's just how it is in academia, and the realities of the hiring cycle, teaching, and university budgets make it so that in academia it's not so easy to change jobs at the drop of a pin. Every professor you know had to navigate the same thing, and I'm sure you'll be able to manage it. One thing that might be helpful is to ask yourself what you really need to be happy, and only aim for jobs that check those boxes. Always climbing for a "better" job is not great for long-term happiness. I advise you to try to become a satisficer instead of an optimizer. Anyway, now at least you know you are very hireable and if you are not happy at A after all, you can probably go on the job market again and find something else.
